# How to convert RECT = [xmin, ymin, width, height] to (x,y)s of an image?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, graphics, computer-vision

I got the coordinates of a rectangle RECT = [xmin, ymin, width, height], which can be used to crop a patch from an image, say ***I***, in Matlab. But instead of cropping the patch, I actually want to the (x,y)s in that rectangle on the image. The current way I'm using is:

```
mask = false(size(I));
mask(RECT(2):RECT(2)+RECT(4), RECT(1):RECT(1)+RECT(3)) = 1;
[xs,ys] = find(mask == 1);
```

This way works, but it takes a long time if I have a large number of images. For example 60,000 images.

So, could you  please advise me if there is any quick way to implement the same function?

Comment: Thanks guys! I found an easy way to got all the coordinates given a RECT = [x_min, y_min, width, height]. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Given RECT = [x_min, y_min, width, height] The method is:

```
XYs = [];
Xs = [x_min:x_min+width]';
Ys = [y_min:y_min+height]';
for i = 1:size(Xs,1)
   XYs = cat(1, XYs, [Xs .* ones(size(Ys,1),1), Ys]);
end
clear Xs Ys
```

Just be careful the result XYs is [columns, rows]. Thanks!

Comment: Did my `meshgrid` method not work for you?  I personally think it's much more efficient than your loop.

Answer (score -1):

If it is a rectangle you wish to edit in an image `I` , then the simplest way is just

```
I(xmin:xmax,ymin:ymax) = whatever;
```

or, in your terms:

```
I(RECT(1):RECT(1)+RECT(3), RECT(2):RECT(2)+RECT(4)) = whatever;
```

without actually creating a mask.

matlab will interpret this as a rectangle (not a diagonal line).

You may as well want to use the form :

```
 I(xmin:xmax,ymin:ymax) = SomeFunction( I(xmin:xmax,ymin:ymax) );
```

I suspect this will be faster than using `meshgrid`.

Comment: The OP wants the **coordinates** of the rectangle - not a more efficient way to set values in an image.  This is already what the OP Is doing combined with using `find`. Quote: _"But instead of cropping the patch, I actually want to the (x,y)s in that rectangle on the image."_  However, you are correct in that using `meshgrid` to set values in an image is inefficient, but that's not the OP's objective.